# Finding the specific child of a component in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, badge

I am creating Badges Or Chips like these[image]

Using the code:

```
<View style = {{flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: 10, marginTop: 5}}>
{this.state.eduModes.map((v, i) => {
  return (
      <Badge
        key={i}
        onPress = {(i) => {
          console.log(i);
        }}
        value={v}
        containerStyle= {{marginRight: 5}}
        textStyle={{ color: 'orange' }}
      />
  )
})}
</View>
```

The user chooses the value from a picker which creates the badge, now what I want is when the user clicks on the badge the badge should be removed. So how can I access the specific badge on which the user clicked so it would disappear on re-rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a new inline function that sends the index of the badge that should be removed to the remove function.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  handlePress = index => {
    this.setState(previousState => {
      const eduModes = [...previousState.eduModes];
      eduModes.splice(index, 1);
      return { eduModes };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginLeft: 10, marginTop: 5 }}>
        {this.state.eduModes.map((v, i) => {
          return (
            <Badge
              key={i}
              onPress={() => this.handlePress(i)}
              value={v}
              containerStyle={{ marginRight: 5 }}
              textStyle={{ color: "orange" }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, how could I have missed that.